# Build Dockerfile on Rasperry Pi OS

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, dockerfile, buildx

I am trying to build a Dockerfile on my Raspberry Pi 4 (Pi OS 10 (buster), armv7l).

I am using `docker buildx build .` which starts fine but runs into problems fetching packages:

```
[build 3/5] RUN apk --no-cache add git build-base:
#6 0.673 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/armv7/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#6 0.735 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main: temporary error (try again later)
#6 0.735 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/armv7/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#6 0.737 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community: temporary error (try again later)
#6 0.737 ERROR: unable to select packages:
#6 0.739 build-base (no such package):
#6 0.739 required by: world[build-base]
#6 0.739 git (no such package):
#6 0.739 required by: world[git]
```

This feels like the apk command is missing a connection, so I guess there might be something I am missing regarding an internet connection for the container (though the previous steps are working fine...)

This is the start of the Dockerfile I am trying to build:

```
# Build container
ARG GOVERSION=1.17.3
FROM --platform=${BUILDPLATFORM} \
    golang:$GOVERSION-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /src
RUN apk --no-cache add git build-base
```

Any ideas?

Comment: (FYI I removed the [tag:apk] tag because it refers not to the Alpine package manager but to Android application bundles.)

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research, I found the cause of my problem: It is due to a bug in the libseccomp2 library (dependency of Docker itself), which is fixed. However it's not pushed to all the repositories, which is affecting 32 bit installs of distros based on Debian Buster.

I had to follow one of the solution posted [here](https://docs.linuxserver.io/faq#libseccomp), which fixed it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).